# the number of ways in which one or more books can be given away

Tags: combinatorics

There are 6 copies of book A, 5 copies of book B and 4 copies of book C. find the number of ways in which one or more books can be given away.

My approach:  $2^{15}$

Comment: What matters here is how many books of each type are selected.

Answer (score 1):

Your answer counts the number of subsets of the books, which would be correct if all the books were distinguishable. However, some of the books are indistinguishable.

Say we place numbered stickers on the books of the same type to distinguish them, so we now have 
$$A_1,A_2,\dots,A_6,B_1,B_2,\dots,B_5,C_1,C_2,C_3,C_4.$$
Your answer of $2^{15}$ counts the following subsets of books as different:
$$\{A_1,A_2,B_3,B_4,B_5,C_1\} \quad \text{and} \quad \{A_4,A_5,B_1,B_2,B_4,C_3\} $$
but without the stickers they both look like:
$$\{A,A,B,B,B,C\}.$$
So you need to count how many ways there are to choose some number of books of type $A$ to give away, some number of books of type $B$ to give away, and some number of books of type $C$ to give away.